# Samsung Legacy 2014 TV not updating application

Tags: samsung-smart-tv, smart-tv

I have followed the steps given in http://developer.samsung.com/tv/develop/legacy-platform-library/art00121/index, and the application appears on the Smart Hub on the TV. However, when I make some changes in the application, and package it again selecting "**Update the packaged files on the server**", do a "**Apps Sync**" and run the application, the updates are not reflected.

I have tried changing the application name and version in config.xml. Only the application name changes in smart hub, but the application when opened is what was installed the first time on the TV.

If a new project is made and the same steps are followed, the new application appears on the smart hub, but an update to it has the same problem. 
Am I missing something while packaging the same application for a second time?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is useful but I believe the device seems to cache the files. I had the same issue today and was quite frustrating.

I managed to find two solutions:

1) shut down the device and re-launch again (connect to server and the Apps Sync)

2) when you export the app in the IDE, make sure you name the package name differently + title & description need to be different too.

[image]

By doing this, Apps Sync will add another app (so you'll have two of the same app, but just click on the last one that appears in the apps list - hope that makes sense). If you want to remove the apps, simply access the widgetlist.xml which will be in the root of your server and then remove the apps references from there.

I hope that helps.

Comment: After trying many combinations, I figured that if you change the version in config.xml, and the title in the above dialog it is enough. You do not need to restart every time and description does not seem to make a difference

Comment: Yeah. The restart was one of two options but in the end I went with option two as well as it was much quicker. Hope the project went well for you.